# When and why does Git update the modification time on .keep packfiles?

Tags: git

I use Git version 2.4.11 in the Cygwin environment on a Windows 7 workstation for source control.

We make a copy of my local Git repository from time to time via Windows `robocopy`, which is sensitive to file modification time.

A little while ago, I made a `.keep` file for my main packfile, reasoning that incremental backups would be able to skip my main packfile, and would therefore be smaller and quicker.

I find, instead, that my packfile's modification time keeps getting updated somehow in ordinary use.  Even though the file is the same length and contains the same bytes as before, this update to the modification time causes `robocopy` to copy it again.

Under what circumstances does Git `touch` packfiles that are `.keep`?  Why does it do this?